# Select all deepest nodes with XPath 1.0 containing text, ignoring markup

Tags: html, xpath, xpath-1.0

I want to extract elements from the HTML page, containing text, ignoring markup. For example, I want to extract node containing the text "Run, Sarah, run!" from https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/run. I know about node test `text()` and function `string()`. I tried them both:
[image: Firefox with the console. Searching "Run, Sarah, run!"]

As you see, if I use `string()` it returns too many nodes (result includes the nodes that include the node I need) and if I use `text()` it returns nothing (because of the `<b>` tag).

How do I find required nodes?

**UPD:** I want all deepest nodes. That means if the Wikitionary page contained this sentence twice, I wanted to select two nodes.

Also, I don't know the node type.

Comment: Are you sure that you're using web-scraping tool with HTML parser that supports XPath 2.0? What is that tool?

Comment: You are right! I messed up. Indeed, I use Splinter (based on Selenium) with Chrome webdriver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`//*[contains(string(.), "Run, Sarah, run!")]` returns *all* elements (starting from `html` node till last descendant node) that contains that string.

`//*[contains(text(), "Run, Sarah, run!")]` returns nothing as `"Run, Sarah, run!"` is compound text from several text nodes, but not from single text node

You can use below to match italic node with required text:

```
'//i[normalize-space()="Run, Sarah, run!"]'
```

If you don't want to specify node name, you can try

```
'//*[normalize-space()="Run, Sarah, run!" and not(./*[normalize-space()="Run, Sarah, run!"])]'
```

Comment: Thank you for an explanation. I think that the last variant is what I need.
But why does it called `normalize-space` if it strips markup?)
Also, I didn't find anything about this behaviour in docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space

Comment: Also, there is some problem with the last solution: I want to get all deepest nodes. That means if the page contains several separate nodes containing the text, I want them all!

Comment: @rominf , I'm not sure I understand what is your desired output... Do you mean you want an array of nodes that contain text?

Comment: Yep, I selected this example for simplicity. See UPD.

Comment: Sorry, I have to undo accepting your answer. Probably it's my fault that I didn't write all the requirements in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. Not very beautiful, but it works and I can produce the XPath using string formatting and make it less ugly.

Comment: I don't like `normalize-space` (what a strange name!), I've used the same logic with `contains(string(.))`.

Comment: I'm getting identical results. What's the difference in my problem?

Comment: @rominf , I guess in your current case there is no difference. Actually XPath can be even shorter: `//*[.="Run, Sarah, run!" and not(./*[.="Run, Sarah, run!"])]`